# Django ошибка изменения ForeignKey в сигналах

Tags: django

Добрый день!
Какой то бред, вообще. Сто раз использовал такую конструкцию, в этом приложение она постоянно используется, прекрасно работает во вьюхах, в консоле, а в сигналах пишет нелепую ошибку:

> Cannot assign "(<Status: Заказ оплачен>,)": "Order.status" must be a "Status" instance.

вот мой файл Signals.py:

```
from robokassa.signals import *
from shop.models import *

def sig(sender, **kwargs):
   order = Order.objects.get(id = kwargs['InvId'])
   oplachen = Status.objects.get(id=2)
   order.status = oplachen,
   order.save()

success_page_visited.connect(sig)
```

я в растерянности. как только не пробовал это исправить..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Принимает за tuple. Запятую после oplachen уберите, все станет ОК.

Comment: точно!!! а я мучаюсь, уже пробовал и напрямую status_id менять и как только не извращался)) вот такая вот незаметная ошибка спасибо!!